# Insert two arrays in one using two methods for each array

Tags: java, arrays

i want to create 3 arrays with objects.The two arrays(pin and age) i want to put them on one array named Alltogether.I use from each method  to return me an array i dont know if this is right i try it.In the end i want to systemout only the array that has all this.

```
package worklin1;

public class worklin1{
    static int N; //from keyboard i have a class userinput
    private String Name;            // name
    private int age;            // age
    private  int costVehicle;   //vehicle
    public worklin1(){}
    public worklin1(String Name, int Age, int cost, String name) {
        Name=name;
        Age=age;
        costVehicle=cost;
    }
    // Access methods
    public String getName(){
        return Name;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
    public int getcostVehicle(){
        return costVehicle;
    }


    // Mutator methods
    public void setName(String name){
        Name=name;
    }
    public void setSurname(String age){
        age=age;
    }
    public void setcostVehicle(int cost){
        costVehicle=cost;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s=name+" "+age+", "+cost+"\t";
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){ //main

        int[] pin= new int[N]; // the first array
        int[] age=new int[]; // the second array.i dont know why it is false this array maybe i use an object as name for an array thats why its false.
        Allmethodtogether[] pin = new Allmethodtogether[N]; // Allmethodotogether is an array.It has the combination of age and the cost.The N is just a number i give from keyboard i dont care about this right now.I just wanted to focus on my problem which is how to combine the two methods(which they give me each one 2 arrays and i will add them in this array name Allmethodtogether).
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // i want to put in an array all the arrays from the methods so i start the counting from 0 until 10.Until the 10 will be saved the pin and after 10 will be saving the array age
            Allmethodtogether[i] = new Vehcost();
            Allmethodtogether[i+10] = new AllAge();
        } //finished //Now i want to display those arrays and i am trying this .

        int y; // i create a variable to save my results from the method
        y=worklin1.Vehcost(int[] pin); // i take the result from the method Vehcost
        System.out.println("Appear all array"+y ); //i want to appear the array.Did i create and an array with objects?
        int k; // i do the same thing as the other
        k=worklin1.Allage(int[] age);
        System.out.println("Appear all array"+k);


    } // end main
    public static int  Vehcost(int[] pin ) { //starting first method 1

        int cost = 0;

        for(int i =0; i < pin.length; i++) {
            cost += pin[i].getcostVehicle();
            pin[i]=getname()+ cost; //i want to save to pin the names and the cost of each one
        }

        return pin[i]; // i  want to return the array pin
    }//end method 1

    public static int  allAge(int[] age ) { //second method
        if(getage() >18 ){ //if age is >18 only then will going to save on the array

            for(int i =0; i < age.length; i++) {
                age += age[i].getage();
            }
        }
        return age; // i want to return the array age
    }// end method 2

}
```

Comment: Can you please reformat your code properly?

Comment: you have a lot of mistakes in your code, can you please make is small and clear?

Comment: i will try  to do it :)

Comment: i try to add comments to understand me what am i doing in each case i hope i help you understand my code what i want

Comment: Little tip: Write comments on code above it. That way you can use multiple lines and it's much more convenient and easier to read.

Comment: now its more clear what am i asking ? :/

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is not clear, what your question is. Maybe you should first try to make your code compilable.